# LWJGL causing runtime error when trying to load PNG as texture: "Problematic frame: C [lwjgl_opengl.dll+0xf46d]"

Tags: opengl, textures, lwjgl

This code returns a 'File Not Found' IOExeption when I enter in an invalid file name and directory (as it should), but when I enter in a valid PNG file, it crashes. The error message tells me the resister and adress values at time of crash, as well as "Problematic frame: C [lwjgl_opengl.dll+0xf46d]", but I don't see where I went wrong (I mostly analysed other code because I don't understand how to texture load).

```
public static int loadTexture( String name ) throws IOException
{
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream( name );

    PNGDecoder decoder = new PNGDecoder( in );

    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect( 3 * decoder.getWidth()*decoder.getHeight() );

    decoder.decode( buf, decoder.getWidth() * 3, PNGDecoder.Format.RGB );
    buf.flip();

    int texture = glGenTextures();
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );

    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, decoder.getWidth(), decoder.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );

    in.close();

    return texture;
}
```

I think if I could use STBImage instead, that would be good, but I honestly don't understand any of them and I found more information on PNGDecoder.

I'm using LWJGL 3.

**Edit:** The error is a runtime error on `glGenTextures();`.

Comment: Which of the lines crashes?

Comment: It doesn’t tell me. It looks like it may be a library problem. I may try it on another computer and see if that helps. It’s had that error with multiple methods of texture loading (PNGDecoder and STBImage), making me think it could be LWJGL and its natives.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the first line, step through it line by line and see when it crashes. Then you know where the problem lies.

Comment: don't you have a crash report saved somewhere? Usually there will be a .log file generated (hs_err_pid####.log). If you search for "Java frames" in that file you will find the method where it crashed. I've also read that OpenGL will crash when you specify `Format.RGB` in `decoder.decode()`but the PNG is RGBA. Just and `if(decoder.hasAlpha())`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the Java frames part of the file. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about this since you didn't upload the full crash report, but either you have no OpenGL context when you call glGenTextures or your LWJGL jar files are from different versions.

So, make sure you call `GL.createCapabilities()` in LWJGL 3 or `Display.create()` in LWJGL 2 before you load the textures.